# change border background based on enum value in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I'm designing a custom control I want the user to be able to change the background color with a custom property.
The background color should be specified by enum called Severity:

*Code*

```cs
public enum Severity
{
    Warning,
    Information,
    Success,
    Error
}
```

*Xaml*

```xml
<Border Background="{DynamicResource InfoBarInformationalSeverityBackgroundBrush}" 
        CornerRadius="4">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ib:InfoBar}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>

<InfoBar Severity="Error"/>
```

I tried the trigger but it didn't seem to work

Update:

*Xaml*

```xml
<Border>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ib:InfoBar}}" 
                             Value="Error">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ib:InfoBar}}" 
                             Value="Success">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

*Code*

```cs
public Severity Severity
{
    get { return (Severity) GetValue(SeverityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SeverityProperty, value); }
}
    
public static readonly DependencyProperty SeverityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Severity", typeof(Brushes), typeof(InfoBar));
```

Comment: "*I tried the trigger*" - where do we see that? And `<InfoBar Severity="Error"/>` means that InfoBar has a property named Severity of type Severity?

Comment: `Register("Severity", typeof(Brushes)` - the DP type here is inconsistent with the type of the `Severity` property. Should be `Register("Severity", typeof(Severity)`.

Comment: @KlausGütter thank you i fixed it but again my control not work and background not changed

Comment: You should remove the `Background="{DynamicResource InfoBarInformationalSeverityBackgroundBrush}"` from the Border element and instead provide the default background in the Style.

Comment: @KlausGütter i did it, but background not changed

Comment: It would be good to have a [mre], i.e. compilable code as small as possible, but still reproducing the problem

Comment: Show complete XAML and Code Behind of your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a converter. Pass your Enum and covert to a color:

```
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color colorDefalut = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#00afef");

        switch ((int)value)
        {
            case (int) Severity. Warning:

                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

            case (int) Severity.Information:

                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.bleu);

            case (int) Severity. Error:
                
                return new SolidColorBrush(colors.Red);

            default:

                return new SolidColorBrush(colorDefalut);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependency property should be registered as a `Severity` instead of `Brushes`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SeverityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Severity), typeof(Severity), typeof(InfoBar));
```

Then your example should work assuming that the `Border` is a visual child of the `InfoBar` control:

```
<b:InfoBar Severity="Warning">
        <Border>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=b:InfoBar}}" Value="Warning">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=b:InfoBar}}" Value="Success">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Severity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=b:InfoBar}}" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</b:InfoBar>
```

Comment: @gittest? Did you fail to get this working?